# How VLAN devices will get automatically IP from DHCP server

Tags: vlan, dhcp

I have one Windows server 2012R2 which has 10.219.1.1 IP address & I also have Cisco Catalyst 2960-X Series which is layer 2, we managed to do inter VLAN routing by updating its firmware, where we got limited routing feature. Now we have made 5 VLANs in it so how do I get automatically IP addresses from my DHCP server for particular VLANs?

Comment: Use IP helper address on your layer 3 VLAN. Command is: `ip helper-address <DHCP Server IP>`

Comment: The switch acts as a dhcp-relay agent. It adds a field to the request so the dhcp server knows which network originated the request.

Comment: Hi Rahul -- I take it the Windows server is the DHCP server?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use DHCP helper address in your middle routers or switches between your dhcp server and your vlan nodes

Take a look of this link: https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_4t/ip_addr/configuration/guide/htdhcpre.html

Hope this helps.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst switch Cisco 2960 is layer2 switch can't configure DHCP scopes configuration in this switch . Window server 2012 R2 can be used as DHCP server . Enable DHCP features on this server and configure DHCP scopes and pools as per your requirement . And connect server in network . Make sure that this dhcp server is reachable from any where in network .

Lan is segregated as 5 Vlans . Accordinglly DHCP server can be configured . Now all the client machines connected  among 5 Vlan receives  automatically ip allocation fron DHCP server.